# ruby-odbc - Error occurred while installing ruby-odbc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Unable to get the odbc adapter working. Here are my comp specs and log. I am unable to make it work

HP
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
ruby - 3.0.0p0
Rails 6.1.3.1

********Log ********

> myname@myname-hp:~/myname/work/ourab/coalesceapp$ rails s -p 3001
> /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/digest.rb:6:
> warning: already initialized constant Digest::REQUIRE_MUTEX
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/digest-3.1.0/lib/digest.rb:20:
> warning: previous definition of REQUIRE_MUTEX was here DEPRECATION
> WARNING: Devise::Models::Authenticatable::BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION
> is deprecated! Use
> Devise::Models::Authenticatable::UNSAFE_ATTRIBUTES_FOR_SERIALIZATION
> instead. (called from  at
> /home/myname/myname/work/ockhamlab/coalesceapp/config/application.rb:7)
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb:8:in
> `<class:Column>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::Deduplicable (NameError) from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb:7:in` module:ConnectionAdapters'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb:5:in
> `<module:ActiveRecord>'   from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb:3:in` '  from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in
> `require'     from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'  from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in
> `register'    from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in` require_with_bootsnap_lfi'   from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in
> `require'     from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bundler/gems/odbc_adapter-8caac599010f/lib/odbc_adapter/column.rb:2:in` module:ODBCAdapter'    from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bundler/gems/odbc_adapter-8caac599010f/lib/odbc_adapter/column.rb:1:in
> `<main>'  from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` require'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in
> `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'  from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in` register'    from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in
> `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'   from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in` require'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bundler/gems/odbc_adapter-8caac599010f/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/odbc_adapter.rb:11:in
> `<main>'  from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` require'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in
> `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'  from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in` register'    from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in
> `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'   from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in` require'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bundler/gems/odbc_adapter-8caac599010f/lib/odbc_adapter.rb:2:in `<main>'    from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` require'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in
> `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'  from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in` register'    from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in
> `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'   from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in` require'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in
> `block (2 levels) in require'     from /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in` each'    from
> /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in
> `block in require'    from /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in` each'    from
> /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in
> `require'     from /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:174:in` require'     from
> /home/myname/myname/work/ockhamlab/coalesceapp/config/application.rb:7:in
> `<main>'  from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` require'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in
> `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'  from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in` register'    from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in
> `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'   from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in` require'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in
> `block in perform'    from <internal:kernel>:90:in` tap'  from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in
> `perform'     from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in` run'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in
> `invoke_command'  from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in` dispatch'    from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in
> `perform'     from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in` invoke'  from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in
> `<main>'  from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` require'     from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in
> `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'  from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in` register'    from
> /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in
> `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'   from /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in` require'     from bin/rails:4:in `' message.txt

********Log ********

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?